# IdentityServer: What is the right grant type to use for the client application?

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, oauth, identityserver4

I have a scenerio not sure which grant type should I be using.

We have a current web application. User will require to login to the our existing web application. Once logged in, user need to click on a button to register himself or log in through identity server and send back a registered/logged-in userId (I think that is the openId). Once received that id, i can link this id to our existing user login table.

Answer (score 0):

That depends both on the technology you're using to build your web app and the user experience you want to offer.

When you have no need for refresh tokens or you have a JavaScript application, the **implicit** flow is recommended. In that case all tokens are transmitted through the browser channel.

The **hybrid** flow is recommended for server-side web applications and native desktop/mobile apps and will also support things like refresh tokens so as to keep your users logged in across browser sessions. This flow uses the browser channel for the identity token and the back channel for access / refresh tokens.

These two grant types cover a lot of the more common scenarios for web apps but there are more to choose from or to take into account. I suggest you read up on that in the [IdentityServer4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html).